# exceptions in windows service - service stops when an exception occurs

Tags: visual-studio-2010, exception, windows-services

I have developed a windows service that watches a folder for new files. My problem is that when an exception occures, service stops working. The main purpose of the service is :
1. watch a folder for file creation
2. read the file 
3. insert file's data in database
What I really want to do is not to loose any file insertion! Every new file must be read and its data be inserted in database.
But if an exception happens, such like "The process cannot access the file 'c:\newfile.txt' because it is being used by another process.", the process stops. My code for service is :

```
public partial class weatherService : ServiceBase
    {
        private FileSystemWatcher FSW;
        private FswHandler Handler;

        public weatherService()
        {
            InitializeComponent();            
        }

        protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
        {
            FSW = new FileSystemWatcher("c:\\cvvv", "*.txt");
            Handler = new FswHandler();

            FSW.Created += Handler.OnEvent;

            FSW.EnableRaisingEvents = true;    

        }

        protected override void OnStop()
        {
            FSW.EnableRaisingEvents = false;
            FSW.Dispose();
        }

        protected override void OnPause()
        {
            FSW.EnableRaisingEvents = false;
        }

        protected override void OnContinue()
        {
            FSW.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
        }
    }
```

And the handler code is :

```
public class FswHandler
    {
        private string[] data;
        private StreamReader reader;
        private StreamWriter sw;

        public void OnEvent(Object source, FileSystemEventArgs Args)
        {
            LogEvent(" [reading file] ");
            readFile(Args.FullPath, Args.Name);
        }

        public void LogEvent(string msg) {
            sw = new StreamWriter("C:\\Users\\Olga\\Desktop\\weatherlog.txt", true);    
            sw.WriteLine("Action : "+ msg +" occured in " + DateTime.Now.ToString());
            sw.Close();
        }
        public void readFile(string path, string filename)
        {
            LogEvent(" [got in readFile] to read file " + filename);
            try
            {
                reader = new StreamReader(path);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                LogEvent(ex.Message);
            }
            try
            {
                reader = File.OpenText(path);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                LogEvent(ex.Message);
            }
            string titlesLine;
            string valuesLine;

            LogEvent(" [getting 1st line] ");

            titlesLine = reader.ReadLine();

            LogEvent(" [getting 2nd line] ");

            valuesLine = reader.ReadLine();

            LogEvent(" [splitting 2nd line] ");
            data = valuesLine.Split(new Char[] { ' ', '\t' });

            LogEvent(" [starting inserting] ");
            insData(filename);

            reader.Close();

        }

        public void insData(string filename) {
            string connString = "server=83.212.92.197;port=3306;database=mydata;uid=distusr;pwd=usdist1";
            MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connString);
            MySqlCommand command = conn.CreateCommand();

            DateTime cdt = System.DateTime.Now;

            String.Format("{0:MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss}", cdt);
            string dt = cdt.ToString();
            int space_pos = dt.IndexOf(" ");
            string date = dt.Substring(0, space_pos);
            string time = dt.Substring(space_pos+1, dt.Length-space_pos+1);

            command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO datainput(filename, measDate, measTime, out2, out3, out4, out5, out6, out7, out8, out9, out10," +
            "out11, out12, out13, out14, out15, out16, out17, out18, out19, out20," +
            "out21, out22, out23, out24, out25, out26, out27, out28, out29, out30," +
            "out31, out32, out33, out34, out35, out36, out37, out38, out39, out40," +
            "out41, out42, out43) VALUES ('" + filename + "','" + date + "','" + time +
            "','" + data[14] + "','" + data[15] + "','" + data[16] + "','" + data[17] + "'," +
            "'" + data[18] + "','" + data[19] + "','" + data[20] + "','" + data[21] + "','" + data[22] + 
            "','" + data[23] + "'," + "'" + data[24] + "','" + data[25] + "','" + data[26] + 
            "','" + data[27] + "','" + data[28] + "'," +"'" + data[29] + "','" + data[30] + 
            "','" + data[31] + "','" + data[32] + "','" + data[33] + "'," + "'" + data[34] + 
            "','" + data[35] + "','" + data[36] + "','" + data[37] + "','" + data[38] + "'," + 
            "'" + data[39] + "','" + data[40] + "','" + data[41] + "','" + data[42] + "','" + data[43] + 
            "'," + "'" + data[44] + "','" + data[45] + "','" + data[46] + "','" + data[47] + 
            "','" + data[48] + "'," + "'" + data[49] + "','" + data[50] + "','" + data[51] +
            "','" + data[52] + "','" + data[53] + "','" + data[54] + "','" + data[55] + "')";

            LogEvent(" [opening database] ");

            try{
                conn.Open();
            }
            catch (Exception ex){
                LogEvent(ex.Message);
            }

            LogEvent(" [executing query] ");

            try
            {
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            catch (Exception ex){
                LogEvent(ex.Message);
            }

            LogEvent(" [data have been inserted] ");


            conn.Close();
        }
    }
```

What can I do to avoid loosing a file? I also tried

```
        protected void DelayExecution(int nSeconds)
        {
            DateTime end = DateTime.UtcNow.AddSeconds (nSeconds);
            while (DateTime.UtcNow < end){}
        }

        try
        {
            reader = File.OpenText(path);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            LogEvent(ex.Message);
            DelayExecution(2);
            readFile(path, filename);
        }
```

but the problem remains. In this case it starts over the function and after the process inserts data in db and then goes again in [getting 1st line]. I use LogEvent so I can debug my service, this is why I have so many LogEvents executing.

Any help would be great...

Answer (score 0):

You can try using this extension method in a loop with a Thread.Sleep:

```
/// <summary>
/// Extension methods for FileInfo
/// </summary>
public static class ExtensionMethods_FileInfo
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Verifies if the file is in use
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="fi">Original FileInfo object</param>
    /// <returns>Returns a boolean value with the state of the file</returns>
    public static Boolean IsInUse(this FileInfo fi)
    {
        try
        {
            if (File.Exists(fi.FullName))
                File.Move(fi.FullName, fi.FullName);
            return false;
        }
        catch (IOException)
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

I suggest you to not write code (other than logging) in your "catch" section, since it can lead to further errors.

```
while (new FileInfo(path).IsInUse())
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);

// Then do your job...
```